# Событие изменения текста в TextInput

Tags: c#, wpf

Наверно не так понял это событие, но оно будет вызываться каждый раз, когда мы что-то вводим в textBox? Сделал так и никакой реакции. Подскажите, как сделать задуманное?

```
private void Password_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Login.Text != "admin" && Password.Password != "123456")
            {
                Information.Content = "Неверный логин или пароль!";
            }
        }
```

Событие прикручено на все 2 textboxa, если что.

Answer (score 2):

[ContentElement.TextInput Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.contentelement.textinput.aspx)

> The `TextInput` event may already be marked as handled by the internal implementations of composited controls. For example, a `TextBox` is a composited control where the **`TextInput` event is already marked as handled**; within its compositing. Controls do this because the control needs to interpret some types of input, such as arrow keys, as having special meaning to that control. If you use `PreviewTextInput` as the event where you attach handlers for text input, you may receive better results. This technique circumvents most cases where control composition has already marked this event as handled and prevents your handler from receiving the event along the event route.

Правильнее было бы использовать событие [TextBoxBase.TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx), либо [ContentElement.PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.contentelement.previewtextinput.aspx).

**UPD.** Не обратил внимание, что используется `PasswordBox`. Для этого контрола необходимо использовать событие [PasswordBox.PasswordChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.passwordchanged.aspx). Отсутствие генерации событий TextInput и TextChanged, видимо, связанно с безопасностью.

Comment: Для логина то работает, без проблем, а для компонента Password - нет. И не найду как заставить...